# How to delete all faces with distance to other object

Tags: python, selection-tools, faces, bmesh, mathematics

I want to delete all faces (of "Mesh") with a distance > 0.5 to the nearest point of an other object ("Sphere").
Unfortunately it deletes the whole object.

Thanks for helping!

[image: Scene]

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import sqrt

# Get the active mesh

obj_sphere = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for face in bm.faces:

    # select face and Sphere
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
    face.select = True
    obj_sphere.select = True

    # get distance for selected objects
    l = []
    for item in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        l.append(item.location)

    distance = sqrt( (l[0][0] - l[1][0])**2 + (l[0][1] - l[1][1])**2 + (l[0][2] - l[1][2])**2)

    # check distance > 0.5 and delete
    if distance > 0.5:
        bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: Related: http://www.blendernation.com/2016/03/03/calculating-distances-two-points-using-geodesic-paths/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came up with similar to @TLousky, test code below only selects faces without the range value.

To use [closest point on mesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=closest_point_on_mesh#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh) you need to put the reference point into the calling object's object space, if not you will get undesired results when away from the origin.

Also note: use vectors to calculate distance.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

L = 0.5 # distance limit
sphere = bpy.data.objects.get("Sphere")
mesh_obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = mesh_obj.data
smwi = sphere.matrix_world.inverted()

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for face in bm.faces:
    v1 = mesh_obj.matrix_world * face.calc_center_median() # global face median
    localPos = smwi * v1  # face cent in sphere local space

    (hit, loc, norm, face_index) = sphere.closest_point_on_mesh(localPos)
    # Edited for new hit success return val.  
    v2 = sphere.matrix_world * loc
    face.select = ((v2 - v1).length > L)
```

test result

[image]

To make it more accurate  consider using the normal returned to determine which point of a face to use.  If the angle between the face normal and the normal to the closest point is ~ 90 use the closest edge,  ~ 180 degrees it's on the inside.

Comment: @Basti edited slightly to take inverting the sphere's world matrix out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This code does the trick, and uses some nice built in functions to make things simpler:

```
import bpy, bmesh

s = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
o = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(  mode   = 'EDIT'     )
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(  action = 'DESELECT' )
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode( type   = 'FACE'     )

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh( o.data )

for f in bm.faces:
    # Calculate the global location of the current face's median point
    gCenterMedian = o.matrix_world * f.calc_center_median()

    # Find the closest point on the Sphere to the current face's median
    loc = s.closest_point_on_mesh( gCenterMedian )[0]

    # Find the distance by calculating the length of the vector between the two points
    distance = ( loc - gCenterMedian).length

    if distance < 0.5: f.select = True

bm.select_flush( True )

# Delete all selected faces
bpy.ops.mesh.delete( type = 'FACE' )

bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
```

As the gif shows, reverse the sign to delete far away faces
[image]

Comment: For some reason got this :

TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types

On this line of code : `gCenterMedian = Plane.matrix_world * face.calc_center_median()`