# Delete "doubles" on different object

Tags: python, mesh, objects, workflow, edit-mode

I have two objects, call them Object 1 and Object 2. The snap vertices threshold (min distance between vertices) is 0.001.

I want to delete all the vertices of Object 2 that:

- have the same location with any vertices of Object 1,
- or have the distance from any vertices of object 1 < threshold (=0.001)

This would be like removing doubles, but it would only compare vertices of Object 2 with vertices of Object 1 then only delete vertices from Object 2

What is a method for easily doing this?

Comment: Probably only possible with python, adding the tag

Comment: How tp deal with objects that share a mesh? Remove a vert from one and it's removed for all objects using that mesh.

Comment: thank you for your help, the 2 object i use should never share a mesh, so we don't have to worry about that, could you please tell me how to run a python script that have no user interface like this ? i searched google but i'm not sure ,thanks ) sorry because i have never use script that does not have user interface,

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit of a brute force approach, base object is context object, checks global vert positions against those of other mesh objects in the context.selected_objects collection.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
# tolerance to use 
TOL = 0.001

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

base_obj = context.object
base_mesh = base_obj.data

bbm = bmesh.new()
bbm.from_mesh(base_mesh)

# a list of global locations of base_mesh_object verts
locs = [base_obj.matrix_world * v.co for v in bbm.verts]

#meshes of selected objecst that aren't base_mesh
mesh_objs = [o for o in context.selected_objects
               if o.type == 'MESH'
               and o != base_obj and o.data != base_mesh]
# their meshes
meshes = [o.data for o in mesh_objs]

for o in mesh_objs:
    def tol(v1, v2):
        return (v1 - v2).length < TOL

    # are there other objects sharing this mesh?
    if meshes.count(o.data) > 1:
        # what to do?
        print("passing on ", o.name)
        continue

    bm = bmesh.new()
    #bm.from_object(o, scene)
    bm.from_mesh(o.data)
    update = False
    for v in bm.verts:
        # find if any global v pos match our list
        rem = [l for l in locs if tol(o.matrix_world * v.co, l)]
        # if so remove
        if len(rem):
            update = True
            bm.verts.remove(v)

    if update:        
        bm.to_mesh(o.data)

    bm.free()
```

A bounding_box search to eliminate objects that can't have  corresponding verts.  Would make an interesting live edit operator.

Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40979/15543

Comment: Thank you very much , I did not expect an answer so soon , i'll try it

Comment: could you please tell me how to run a python script that have no user interface like this ? i searched google but i'm not sure it's the correct way ,thanks, sorry because i have never use script that does not have user interface , i have to rename "context" object to "object1" right ? (object1 is the object that vertices are not deleted)

Comment: text editor, make a new text, paste script in.  Right click and choose run script.  Always save before running scripts, just in case.

Comment: Python for blender is installed with blender.  You don't need to install python on your system to run the script.  By text editor I mean the blender text editor area.

Comment: Thank you i found the text editor :D but please tell me how i let the script know which object is object1, which is object2 (i guess object2 is the selected object ,right ?) sorry for asking too much because i tried rename object but it still not work

Comment: It works on selected mesh objects (outlined in red (default theme) , the last selected is the context.object (outlined in orange)  The context object is the base object (object1).  Will remove corresponding verts from the other selected mesh objects.

Comment: Thank you so much, i 'll try it :) i really appreicate your efforts